# Bind JSON to Angularjs input

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I got some JSON like this:

```
[{
    "Id": 0,
    "Text": "Item 1",
    "Selected": 1
}, {
    "Id": 1,
    "Text": "Item 2",
    "Selected": 1
}]
```

And an Input like this:

```
<input type="text"
 value="{{question.postObjs}}"
```

What I want is the only the property "Text" as a list in the input.

```
Item 1, Item 2, ...
```

Is this even possible? I trying around like a while, got nothing to work :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller :

```
scope.text = '';    
for (var value in scope.question.postObjs){
    scope.text = scope.text + value.Text;
}
```

in your input :

```
<input type="text" value="{{text}}" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a method in AngularController like this

```
$scope.getText(){
   // which will return ["Item1", "Item2"]
}
```

And in view you can use the method to populate the value.